# How do I manipulate a variable that has been set to an object?

Tags: ruby, class, module, function

I have written a module similar to the following:

```
module One
  class Two
    def self.new(planet)
      @world = planet
    end
    def self.hello
      "Hello, #{@world}"
    end
  end
end
```

I was going to manipulate the module in the following way:

```
t = One::Two.new("World")
puts t.hello
```

Obviously, however, `self.hello` is not in `t`'s scope. I realize that I could do the following:

```
t = One::Two
t.new("World")
puts t.hello
```

The previous method doesn't feel right, so I am looking for an alternative.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: Ummm... I should have stated that I wrote a module similar to the one above.

Comment: In Ruby, it's more common to do two spaces per indent: https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#source-code-layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
module One
  class Two
    # use initialize, not self.new
    # the new method is defined for you, it creates your object
    # then it calls initialize to set the initial state.
    # If you want some initial state set, you define initialize.
    # 
    # By overriding self.new, One::Two.new was returning the planet,
    # not an initialized instance of Two.
    def initialize(planet)
      @world = planet
    end

    # because One::Two.new now gives us back an instance,
    # we can invoke it
    def hello
      "Hello, #{@world}"
    end
  end
end

t = One::Two.new 'World'
t.hello # => "Hello, World"
```

Answer (score 1):

You should create an `initialize` method and not a `self.new` to create objects of a class. `SomeClass.new` will call that `initialize` method.

If you want to access instance variables, you should do it using instance methods. So instead of `def self.hello` do `def hello`. If you want class methods you should also use class variables. To do so, instead of `@some_var` use `@@some_var`.